# Scala - Use predicate function to summarize list of strings

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I need to write a function to analyze some text files.
For that, there should be a function that splits the file via a predicate into sublists. It should only get the values after the first time the predicate evaluates to `True` and afterwards start a new sublist after the predicate was `True` again.
For Example:
`List('ignore','these','words','x','this','is','first','x','this','is','second')`
with predicate
`x=>x.equals('x')`
should produce
`List(List('this','is','first'),List('this','is','second'))`

I've already done the reading of the file into a `List[String]` and tried to use `foldLeft` with a case statement to iterate over the List.

```
words.foldLeft(List[List[String]]()) {
      case (Nil, s) => List(List(s))
      case (result, "x") => result :+ List()
      case (result, s) => result.dropRight(1) :+ (result.last :+ s)
    }
```

There are 2 problems with this though and I can't figure them out:

- This does not ignore the words before the first time the predicate
  evaluates to `True`
- I can't use an arbitrary predicate function

If anyone could tell me what I have to do to fix my problems it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your example a little bit:

```
def foldWithPredicate[A](predicate: A => Boolean)(l: List[A]) =
  l.foldLeft[List[List[A]]](Nil){
      case (acc, e) if predicate(e) => acc :+ Nil //if predicate passed add new list at the end
      case (Nil, _) => Nil //empty list means we need to ignore elements
      case (xs :+ x, e) => xs :+ (x :+ e) //append an element to the last list
  }

val l = List("ignore","these","words","x","this","is","first","x","this","is","second")
val predicate: String => Boolean = _.equals("x")

foldWithPredicate(predicate)(l) // List(List(this, is, first), List(this, is, second))
```

There's one problem performance related to your approach: [appending is very slow on immutable lists](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).
It might be faster to prepend elements on the list, but then, of course, all lists will have elements in reversed order (but they could be reversed at the end).

```
def foldWithPredicate2[A](predicate: A => Boolean)(l: List[A]) =
  l.foldLeft[List[List[A]]](Nil){
      case (acc, e) if predicate(e) => Nil :: acc
      case (Nil, _) => Nil
      case (x :: xs, e) => (e :: x) :: xs
  }.map(_.reverse).reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to use `span` to split the items into the next sublist and the rest in a single call. The following code assumes Scala 2.13 for `List.unfold`:

```
def splitIntoBlocks[T](items: List[T])(startsNewBlock: T => Boolean): List[List[T]] = {
  def splitBlock(items: List[T]): (List[T], List[T]) = items.span(!startsNewBlock(_))

  List.unfold(splitBlock(items)._2) {
    case blockIndicator :: rest => Some(splitBlock(rest))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

And the usage:

```
scala> splitIntoBlocks(List(
  "ignore", "these", "words",
  "x", "this", "is", "first",
  "x", "this", "is", "second")
)(_ == "x")

res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(this, is, first), List(this, is, second))
```